# How to fix size problems using flask and matplotlib to generate plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6cbB.png)I am setting up a web application and I want to be able to make plots using matplotlib and flask. For one of the plots, I had to use "plt.tight_layout()" to be able to read the labels. My problem now is that I would to adjust the size of the plots to have the same dimensions in the y axis in both of them.

I am using a Python 2.7.16 anaconda enviroment on macOS Mojave (Version 10.14.4).

I have tried to use the following functions:
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (5,1)
plt.figure(figsize=(5,1))

The only function that worked was:
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(9.0, 1.78)
but I am not able to set it up manually

```py
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, g, render_template
import requests
import base64
from cStringIO import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/callback/")
def song_analysis():

    # Making a plot
    img = StringIO()
    plt.scatter(names,valence, color=[ 'deeppink','lightpink','lime','orange','blue','green','red','cyan','magenta','yellow','black','white','wheat', 'black', 'indigo', 'snow', 'orchid', 'steelblue', 'grey','aqua'])
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.tight_layout() 
    plt.savefig(img,format='png')
    plt.close()
    img.seek(0)
    plot_url = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue())

    img2= StringIO()
    plt.scatter(names,speechiness, color=[ 'deeppink','lightpink','lime','orange','blue','green','red','cyan','magenta','yellow','black','white','wheat', 'black', 'indigo', 'snow', 'orchid', 'steelblue', 'grey','aqua'])
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(img2,format='png')
    plt.close()
    img2.seek(0)
    plot_url2 = base64.b64encode(img2.getvalue())

    return render_template("index.html", info_name = [display_name],  plot_url=plot_url, plot_url2=plot_url2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port=PORT)
```

Including these lines in the html file:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ plot_url }}" width="800">
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ plot_url2 }}" width="800">
```